# Make local website available to all devices in local network

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have created a LAMP server and in there I host a couple of websites. 
These websites are currently available only when I access them from my Ubuntu machine.
 How can I modify the virtual hosts so that all the devices connected in the network can access these websites too ?

Websites' `.conf` file, located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ looks like this:

Website1.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@website1.com
  ServerName website1.com
  ServerAlias www.website1.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website1.com/public

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Website2.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@website2.com
  ServerName website2.com
  ServerAlias www.website2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website2.com/public

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The hosts file looks like this: 
`127.0.0.1   localhost website1.com website2.com`

Both of these websites can be accessed from my Ubuntu machine by simply entering their names in the browser, but any other device in the network has no access to them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things.

#### 1. Setup Apache virtual host

Virtual host must listen to your private IP, not localhost.
Find your private IP using `ifconfig` command in terminal and look for it in the output.

```
$ ifconfig
...
wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.88.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
...
```

My private ip is **192.168.88.11**

Virtual host must listen to it:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.88.11:80>
```

> Note! Maybe *:80 also works!

#### 2. Setup DNS server in your local network.

Other machines in the local network must know where is the **website1.com**. DNS server must resolve **website1.com** to **192.168.88.11**.

My router is MikroTik. And through the admin panel, using router's terminal, I can configure Static DNS of domains to resolve to internal ip.

```
/ip dns static add name=website1.com address=192.168.88.11
```

Also I can use regular expressions to match many domains using one static record.
Regular expression below matches all *.lan* domains: *foo.lan*, *bar.lan*, *anysite.lan*, etc.. And all of them will be resolved to 192.168.88.11.

```
/ip dns static add regexp=".+\.lan" address=192.168.88.11
```

You have to find out capabilities of your router to set it up.